# Dependency Injection instead of Static Block

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to know how to use DI instead Static Block

```
private static String p1;

private static String p2;

private static String p3;

private static interface i1;

static {

Interface1  i2 =    new Class1  ( new Class2 ( p1 ,  p2 ) );

Class2      c1 =    new Class2  ( p3 , parameter);

i1         = //some statement

}
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? What is wrong with the given code?

Comment: The first problem is having those statics at all. Except for actual constants (like named strings), fields should almost always be instance fields.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use DI in Spring you need to use @Component or @Service on top of the classes that you want to inject, like this:

```
@Component
class Class1 implements Interface1 {
...
}

@Component
class Class2 {
 ...
}
```

and now in the class where you want to inject beans do like this:

```
@Component
class ClassOfInjection {
 @Autowired
private Class1 c1;

@Autowired
private Class2 c2;

}
```

you can find more details [here](https://www.baeldung.com/inversion-control-and-dependency-injection-in-spring).

Comment: What should I write instead
"Interface1  i2 =    new Class1  ( new Class2 ( p1 ,  p2 ) );
Class2      c1 =    new Class2  ( p3 , parameter);"
in static block ?
do I need to use @PostConstruct and if yes how do I replace the code in static block

Comment: You can also use DI in the case of Class2. Instead of using Class2 as an argument constructor, you can declare Class2 as a Spring managed bean by using Component and inject Class2 into Class1 by using Autowired. You can read more in the link posted.